# Form submits empty values. How do I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I've been having problems with a form of this website of mine. The form is supposed to update some variables of my website, so they change into the new input, instead of just adding more to the database.

The thing is, I want the form to be able to pass even if some input areas are empty, but I DON'T WANT for the empty values to be put in the place of the previous values.

For instance, I have a button name "apendix". I only want to edit that one, so I only type on the corresponding input area, hence I only update that one. But once I hit submit, all input areas are submitted, and the blank ones take the place of their former variables. I don't want this. I want only the form with value != '' or null to be updated.

This is my code:

```
<script>
function validate(){
    var formId = document.getElementById("configForm");
    var allInputs = formId.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var input, i;

    for (i=0; input = allInputs[i]; i++){
        if (input.value == null || input.value == ""){
            input.setAttribute("name", "");
        }
    }
} </script>

<form method="post" action="" id="configForm" onsubmit="validate()">
<label for="home">Home:</label>
<br>
<input type="text"  id="home" name="home">
<br>
<label for="apendix">Apêndice:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="apendix">
<br>
<label for="about">Sobre:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="sobre">
<br>
<label for="contato">Contato:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="contato">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Carregar" name="submit"> </form>
```

Important: I don't want any of the input areas to be obligatory. Thank you for your time in advance.

(Also I don't quite get jQuery yet so it would be good to leave any response in javaScript, if that is the way to go, if possible. Thanks.)

**UPDATE**

Here is the output in MY CGI:

home    Test1

apendix Test2

sobre   Test3-next_is_blank

contato

submit

Carregar

[Here is a print, if it makes things clearer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Iio.jpg) As it can be seen, empty values are being posted. I don't want this, is all. What do? Also, for some reason, the screen alerts "undefined" after submit.

**UPDATE 2**

What happens is that my website SELECTS from the my MySQL database. The values in the database are updated accordingly to the $_POST values acquired in the forms. To solve this, I believe, all that is need is to the $_POST not to be updated if the input values in the form be left empty, but I don't know how to do it.

```
    $home = $_POST["home"];
    $apendix = $_POST["apendix"];
    $sobre = $_POST["sobre"];
    $contato = $_POST ["contato"];

    $query = "UPDATE form SET 
    home= '$home',
    apendix= '$apendix',
    sobre= '$sobre',
    contato= '$contato'
    WHERE id='1'";
```

such is my (simplified) database query. How can I prevent $_POST from being updated if left blank?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is on the other side when the values are being displayed. That is, you need the results page to filter out empty fields too.

Comment: The output page only SELECTS data from my MySQL database. The values in the database are updated according to the values acquired in $_POST values. The problem that is happening is that $_POST values are being updated even if left blank. I don't want them to be updated if left blank, but I can't grasp how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a tool like Fiddler (web debugging proxy) to see that the values are actually being POSTed?  See https://jsfiddle.net/mmwn1L5g/ how only the values selected are POSTed?  Are you sure your server side code is correct and not clearing the other values?

Try POSTing to the action below to see your POST values and post them for us.

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/cgi-bin/mycgi.pl" id="configForm" onsubmit="alert(typeof validate);validate()" target="_blank">
```

Comment: If you put an alert in validate(), does it fire?  Does the HTML actually look like this, or is it structured in some other way?  It sure seems to me like the onsubmit is not running.

Answer (score 0):

//Sorry.
  // Maybe it is good for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
function validate(){
var formId = document.getElementById("configForm");
var allInputs = formId.getElementsByTagName("input");
var input, i;

for (i=0; input = allInputs[i]; i++){
    if (input.value == null || input.value == ""){
        //Disable tag null or ""
        input.disabled = true;
    }
}
} </script>

<form name="yourForm" id="configForm" action="" onsubmit="validate()"     method="post">
<label for="home">Home:</label>
<br>
<input type="text"  id="home" name="home">
<br>
<label for="apendix">Apêndice:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="apendix">
<br>
<label for="about">Sobre:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="sobre">
<br>
<label for="contato">Contato:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="contato">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Carregar" name="submit"> </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay. I will check it in my server :D

Comment: I have a check with the client file. This is okay. I put only data to post: This is json format from client side: { "home": "A", "apendix": "B", "sobre": "C", "submit": "Carregar" }. Now you have to edit this code at Server side:    $query = "UPDATE form SET 
    home= '$home',
    apendix= '$apendix',
    sobre= '$sobre',
    contato= '$contato'
    WHERE id='1'";. Please check value before make update statement. What language are you using in Server side.

Answer (score -1):

It is not dificult. You can you attribute 'required' in HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<form method="post" action="" id="configForm">
<label for="home">Home:</label>
<br>
<input type="text"  id="home" name="home" required>
<br>
<label for="apendix">Apêndice:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="apendix" required>
<br>
<label for="about">Sobre:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="sobre" required>
<br>
<label for="contato">Contato:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="contato" required>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Carregar" name="submit"> </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Good luck.

Comment: no, no, not quite. I've tried it. It makes inputs become obligatory. I want none of them to be obligatory, but I want only for the ones which input value differs from null or empty to be uploaded. The ones left empty, not, so that empty values don't take the place of their former values.

Comment: in other words, I don't want empty inputs to be sent to the server.